# How to change the default text editor in R when in Linux?

Tags: linux, r, vi

I am programming using R in Linux and each time I want to edit a function by typing

```
fix(FunctioName)
```

The VI editor is used and for me, it is not that handy, I want to change it and make it an other one for example nano.
I am connecting to our school server so I have only shell, no graphical interface.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Honestly; use a terminal multiplexer.  I prefer gnu screen. Learning curve is more than worth it.

Comment: I have only SSH access, no graphical interface.

Comment: A multiplexer is designed for a non-graphical terminal such as when you are using SSH.  `screen` is nice, but I would recommend `tmux`---it can split windows vertically among other things.

Comment: Oh, great, I have seen tmux but it is dosn't support Red hat, I have installed GNU screen  instead but I am still learning it :).

Comment: multiplexing is not the answer here.  Vi is being invoked to edit an R data structure or function that is serialised on demand, and deserialised when editing is complete.

Comment: Yeah, right Alex, well but for me I didn't know about those screen multiplexers. :)

Comment: Why don't you try Emacs + ESS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always, export the desired editor in `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL` before starting.

Comment: You mean that they are environment variables or I must change them in a specific config file.

Answer (score 5):

Or in R, to override the environment variable:

```
options(editor = "nano")
```

Comment: Yeah, this is also nice and more handy

Comment: how to select "Sublime Text"?