# Can i select nano or gedit to be my editor in R?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the default text editor in R when in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221310/how-to-change-the-default-text-editor-in-r-when-in-linux)

```
> x=c(1,2,3,4)  
> edit(x)
```

when i input it,the vi editor will open ,but i don't like vi,can i make nano or gedit to be my edit in  R after i input edit(x)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution depends upon how you want to solve the problem.

- You can set the `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` environment variables to the text editor of your choice, probably in your shell startup scripts (see `~/.bashrc` if this is all new to you).
- If your distribution uses the `/usr/bin/sensible-editor` tool, you can use the `select-editor(1)` tool to update your choice.
- You can set the `/etc/alternatives/editor` or similar files to the editor you wish, iff you want the change to be made system-wide for all users, and your system uses the `update-alternatives(8)` mechanism to manage which specific tool to use for which tasks.

Answer (score -1):

i get it .
my system is debian , in shell
nano  /etc/profile
add a line
export  EDITOR='/usr/bin/nano'
reboot 
it's ok.

Comment: you almost certainly don't need to reboot! Just open a new shell/terminal window, or ". /etc/profile"